# How Azure Sphere providing security in hybrid system where it is embedded with other MCU?

Tags: azure, security, iot, azure-sphere

Azure Sphere with MT3620 is secured but when it is embedded with other MCU like Pi or NodeMCU then how it is making this system secured?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Sphere platform is an end-to-end solution for creating highly-secured, connected MCU devices. It consist of 3 elements.:

- **Azure Sphere certified microcontrollers (MCUs):** A new cross-over
  class of MCUs that combines both real-time and application processors
  with built-in Microsoft security technology and connectivity. Each
  chip includes custom silicon security technology from Microsoft,
  inspired by 15 years of experience and learnings from Xbox, to secure
  this new class of MCUs and the devices they power.
- **Azure Sphere OS:** This OS is purpose-built to offer unequalled
  security and agility. Unlike the RTOSes common to MCUs today, our
  defense-in-depth IoT OS offers multiple layers of security. It
  combines security innovations pioneered in Windows, a security
  monitor, and a custom Linux kernel to create a highly-secured
  software environment and a trustworthy platform for new IoT
  experiences.
- **Azure Sphere Security Service:** A turnkey, cloud service that guards
  every Azure Sphere device; brokering trust for device-to-device and
  device-to-cloud communication through certificate-based
  authentication, detecting emerging security threats across the entire
  Azure Sphere ecosystem through online failure reporting, and renewing
  security through software updates. It brings the rigor and scale
  Microsoft has built over decades protecting our own devices and data
  in the cloud to MCU powered devices.

These capabilities come together to enable Azure Sphere to meet all 7 properties of a highly secured device – making it a first of its kind solution( refer [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-microsoft-azure-sphere-secure-and-power-the-intelligent-edge/)).

Would you minding sharing with us more about your usecase where you need to embed Azure Sphere with other MCUs?

Comment: Actually we are making a conveyer belt carrying nut-bolt to check the nut on different quality parameter.We will be using different sensors like weight, camera,proximity and actuators , motors etc.At present we are using Pi board. For showcasing our capability in security and to give them assurance about security,we want to embed Sphere chip-sets into our pi or Arduino board.This is why i am asking how Sphere chip will make our device secure? what extra feature it is providing to our device?

Comment: There are seven properties that highly secure devices should provide. And you can refer the detail info from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/SevenPropertiesofHighlySecureDevices.pdf) about how the security feature by adding the **Pluton security subsystem** to the exists MCU.